# How to put a textbox in the right corner at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I want to put a text box in the right corner of the page, in the bottom using html.

I wrote this code, it works, but i'm not sure if it's correct.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title> Test </title>
<style type="text/css">
.poz
{
position:absolute;bottom:15px; right:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="email"; div class="poz"/></div>
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I mean, i am not sure if it's ok to put this part of code "div class="poz"/>" .

Comment: Review your code... You open a div inside the input tag.

Comment: <div class="poz"/><input type="text" name="email"> </div>  .... i think this is ok.

Comment: Yes, now It's correct.

Comment: @Eleanordum, you are using a self-closing, opening div element...should be <div class="poz"><input type="text" name="email"> </div>

Answer (score 2):

```css
.poz{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="poz">
```

Tidying your code a little bit.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Test </title>
<style type="text/css">
.poz
{
position:absolute;bottom:15px; right:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="email" class="poz">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not valid HTML.  I would place the class on the form element and remove the closing </div> (which makes it invalid HTML).

```
<form class="poz">
<input type="text" name="email"/>
</form>
```